# Visual Studio Test task - identifying flaky tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

VSTS sprint 127 introduced some options for identifying flaky tests in the **Visual Studio Test** task.

Are there plans to also introduce this for the **Run Functional Tests** task?

Comment: SO isn't the right place to ask marketing questions about product content.

Comment: It's clearly not a marketing question.
Granted, I could post a suggestion on UserVoice.

Answer (score -1):

You can vote this UserVoice: [flaky tests in Run Functional Test task](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32703796-flaky-tests-in-run-functional-test-task).